# join with a separator added at the end when not empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I need to append all elements in `list_` to a `string`; at the end I need to add a suffix. A dot '.' has to separate all elements:

```
list_ = args[f(n) : f(n+1)]
if list_:
  string += '.' + '.'.join(list_) + '.' + suffix # works except when list_ is empty
else:
  string += '.' + suffix
# list_ isn't used after this
```

Can I rewrite it in a simpler way in one line? If `join` added a separator after each element, it would just this:

```
string += '.' + '.'.join(args[f(n) : f(n+1)]) + '.' + suffix
```

Edit

I just learned that:

Slices are copies even if they are never assigned to: [Does Python do slice-by-reference on strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722006/does-python-do-slice-by-reference-on-strings)

But islice may be even worse since it iterates through the start of the list: [itertools.islice compared to list slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738096/itertools-islice-compared-to-list-slice)

Some alternatives are discussed here: [Avoiding unnecessary slice copying in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328171/avoiding-unnecessary-slice-copying-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with this (updated to reflect edits to the question):

```
'.'.join([''] + args[f(n):f(n+1)] + [suffix])
```

*EDIT*: taking inspiration from sblom's and unutbu's answers, I might *actually* do this:

```
from itertools import chain, islice
string = '.'.join(chain([string],  islice(args, f(n), f(n+1)), [suffix]))
```

if I were concerned about the memory cost of slicing `args`. You can use a tuple `(string,)` or a list `[string]` for the string and the suffix; given that they're one element each, there's no significant difference in memory usage or execution time, and since they're not being stored, you don't have to worry about mutability. I find the list syntax a little cleaner.

However: I'm not sure if Python actually creates a new list object for a slice that is only going to be used, not assigned to. If it doesn't, then given that `args` is a proper list, using `islice` over `[f(n):f(n+1)]`doesn't save you much of anything, and in that case I'd just go with the simple approach (up top). If `args` were a generator or other lazily evaluated iterable with a very large number of elements, *then* `islice` might be worth it.

Answer (score 4):

If `list_` is a generator (or can be trivially changed to be one), you can get away without materializing any lists at all using `chain()` from `itertools`.

```
from itertools import chain
'.'.join(chain(('',),list_,(suffix,)))
```

(This takes inspiration from David Zaslavsky's answer.)

Comment: I like this approach - but I'm not sure if it's easy to create a generator that returns a slice of an existing list?

Comment: Sure, you can use `itertools.islice(list_, f(n), f(n+1))`.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: I guess in light of what I've learned (see the update to the question), the `islice` has terrible performance on a list... I would use this approach if I had a true generator.

Answer (score 4):

Also riffing on [David Zaslavsky answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9104136/190597):

```
string = '.'.join([string] + list_ + [suffix])
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that there is [no addition of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349311/python-string-join-is-faster-than-but-whats-wrong-here/1350289#1350289).

Answer (score 1):

```
string += ('.' + '.'.join(list_) if list_ else '') + '.' + suffix
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that `list_` is actually an expression; I was hoping to avoid creating an extra variable for it (see update to my question)..

Comment: Well, you already do that on your code... Then go with David's code if you don't matter creating 2 extra lists.

Comment: Yes, in my case, it's not a performance issue, just making the code look simple.